what is "a day of work" to an attorney?
So due to repeated and unreasonably long delays, at times weeks, of completing deliverables of my application, and due to my expressing concerns and possibly halting the project, my attorney has offered to credit my account with "a day of work". Due to yet another delay today, they now offer to credit my account with "two days of work".
A "day of work" is 8 hours in the regular business world. So two days of work is a credit for 16 hours of work? This would be a significant portion of the total balance so far.
Obviously, most attorneys do not spend all 8 hours of the day on one client's project. And based on the invoice that is generated so far, the attorney spent variable hours, with a max of only 4, per day, with many gap days of no work at all, on my project so far.
Questions:

I have not replied to the attorney's emails yet. But if we were to disagree on what they meant by "two days of work", do you think I have a case for interpreting it to mean
16 hours.
Is this a common practice in the patent drafting industry, where a credit is given to the client for unreasonably long delays of deliverables?
In the patent industry, is "a day of work" a common phrase? If so, how many hours is that taken to mean?


Have you considered simply asking the attorney (or their staff) the direct question of how many billable hours you will be credited exactly for the delays? Note that there is also the question of whether it is possible for patent practitioners to be held liable for unreasonable delays that cause loss of patent rights in certain circumstances. If so, I wouldn't work with an attorney who takes such risks willy nilly. You haven't stated how long your application has been in draft though - it might not be unreasonable from a legal standpoint.
